# Geometry of complex number

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm having a hard time understand the geometry of complex number. My professor showed these two examples in class and say it's very easy to recognize their geometry, but it doesn't seem easy for me at all.

Here are the examples:

a) $$z=\frac{a+dx+cx^2+bcx +i(ax+dx^2 -cx+b)}{1+x^2}$$

b) $$z=\frac{a-cx+i(b-dx)}{1-x}$$

where $a,b,c,d$ are fixed and $x$ is a real number.

On part a), some of my classmate say it's a circle, but I don't know how can they see that. I wonder if anyone would please explain it to me.

Comment: try calculating $|z|$.

Comment: I tried b), and got $|z|=\frac{\sqrt{a^2 +b^2-2x(ac+bd)+x^2(c^2+d^2)}}{1-t}$. Assumming this is the radius, what does this tell me?

Comment: (a) is an ellipse. To see that, imagine $x = \tan\frac{\theta}{2}$, then the real and imaginary part of $z$ are some linear combination of $\cos\theta$ and $\sin\theta$ plus some constant term. (b) is a straight line, sort of boring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have here parametric descriptions of curves in a $u$, $v$ coordinate system.

For example, in case of a), if  $a=1$, $b=2$, $c=3$, $d=4$ and $0\le x\le10000$ then we have:

[image]

The complex numbers do not play an important role in this case. You could say simply that $$u(x)=\frac{a+dx+cx^2+bcx}{1+x^2}$$ and $$v(x)=\frac{ax+dx^2 -cx+b}{1+x^2}$$ where $x$ is the parameter and $u$, $v$ are the coordinates.

Comment: so you plug $u(x)$ and $v(x)$ into calculator and see the graph?

Comment: If not a calculator but in an excel sheet. Then I graphed the corresponding u,v values.

Comment: just to be sure, for b), I got $u(x)=\frac{a-c}{1-x}$ and $v(x)=\frac{b-dx}{1-x}$, these 2 coordinate form a line, Am I correct?

Comment: Yes. Yes. Yes. Yes.